# What is the use of command?

Tags: magento2, command

```
php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy
```

What is the use of this above command?
Explain briefly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Trick :** use `php bin/magento`, this will output all commands with their purpose

[image]

So :

`dev:source-theme:deploy` = `Collects and publishes source files for theme.`

Comment: What is the use of creating less file in pub/static?

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to create symlinks to LESS files.
Please check below URL which will help.
URL: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-less-sass.html

Answer (score 3):

This command runs to create `symlinks to LESS files` in project.

> dev:source-theme: deploy: Collects and publishes source files for the
>   theme.

Example:

To create LESS files for the frontend theme named VendorName/themeName in the en_US locale using a CSS file named `<magento_root>/pub/static/frontend/VendorName/themeName/en_US/css/styles-l.css`, enter the following command:

```
bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --type="less" --locale="en_US" --area="frontend" --theme="VendorName/themeName" css/styles-l
```

For more details refer official document:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-less-sass.html

**Check symlink file**

[image]

Comment: How we can check this , if symlinks created or not?

Comment: Hi priya check image to check symlink

Comment: Yes. Thank You.

Comment: It is creating less file in pub/Static , and what is the use of this when creating this less files??

Answer (score 0):

The command dev:source-theme: deploy is used to deploy a Magento 2 theme. It copies the files and directories from the theme source directory to the Magento root directory. It also updates the theme registration and sets it as a deployable theme. This command is useful for deploying a custom theme quickly and easily.